# Assigning Numeric Range to MATLAB Symbols

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have constant symbols such as

```
t = sym('t')
c = sym ('c')
```

but I have to restrict these symbols with a constraint stating that t is between 0 and 1 (greater equal to zero, smaller equal to one). For c just greater and equal to zero.

I can easily assign a number in matlab by just denoting

```
t = 0;
```

but I need help to put these symbols in an interval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
assume(t > 0);
assumeAlso(t < 1);
```

Then, you can decide things like

```
isAlways(t^2 < 1)
```

For the `> 0` part, you can use the abbreviation

```
c = sym('c', 'positive')
```